# In R, how can the p-value during pairwise t tests without adjustment be different than the p-value of the t test alone?

Tags: r, anova, t-test, post-hoc

In R, I was running pairwise t tests after a significant ANOVA. To understand better how pairwise t tests work, I set the method to adjust p-values to `'none'`, I was thus expecting to have exactly the same as if I was comparing 'manually' each group. However, this does not seem to be the case.

Why is that?

Here is an example.

**My data:**

> df <- structure(list(treatment = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 
>                                                3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 10L, 
>                                                10L, 10L, 10L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 
>                                                6L, 6L, 6L, 6L), .Label = c("oa", "oa_bhb_1000", "oa_bhb_500", 
>                                                                            "oa_bhb_5000", "oa_d_phe_10", "oa_d_phe_100", "oa_d_phe_50", 
>                                                                            "oa_l_phe_10", "oa_l_phe_100", "oa_l_phe_50"), class = "factor"), 
>                        intensity = c(952343, 963296, 981994, 983969, 1258960, 918174, 
>                                      1273620, 1281570, 1103510, 1154570, 1191380, 1063730, 974519, 
>                                      948350, 911960, 892873, 1171440, 1066490, 1027280, 1004430, 
>                                      1047480, 1185930, 987433, 1179250, 962765, 1107980, 1225000, 
>                                      1054180, 1137860, 1239670, 998971, 1095830, 1166230, 1183520, 
>                                      991854, 897242, 839749, 864329, 929698, 678285)), .Names = c("treatment", 
>                                                                                                   "intensity"), class = "data.frame", row.names = 41:80)

**Running the ANOVA:**

```
summary(aov (intensity ~ treatment, data = df))
```

p-value = 0.00102

**Running the pairwise t tests without p-value adjustment:**

```
pairwise.t.test (df$intensity, df$treatment, p.adjust.method = 'none')
```

Example, the p-value of the t test comparing treatment `oa` with treatment `oa_bhb_500` is `0.00606`.

But if I run this test manually:

```
t.test (df$intensity[1:4], df$intensity[5:8])
```

I get a p-value of `0.09493`.

How can that be? Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 7):

Because the first one fits a model to the data for all the treatments and thus uses all the data to estimate the error variance; whereas the manually done test uses the data from only those two treatments.

Comment: I see. Should the second (the manual test) be less trusted you think?

Comment: If the assumption of equal population variances is true, then the pooled test is better because it uses all available information about that common variance. If the assumption is strongly violated, then the manual t tests are better.

Answer (score 1):

You need to disable pooled sd in the pairwise function to get the same result.

```
pairwise.t.test (df$intensity, df$treatment, p.adjust.method = 'none', pool.sd = FALSE)
```